# TS start complaining about KEY added by decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator

I did create a decorater function called `KeyAdder` also a class named `User`.
I decorated the class with `KeyAdder` and i expected to have a `key` on my instance object.
But when i tried to access that property i got an error:
`Property 'version' does not exist on type 'User'`.

Here is code:

```
function KeyAdder(target: Function) {
    target.prototype.key = 'value';
}

@KeyAdder
class User {
    constructor(
        public username: string,
    ) {}
}


const u = new User("MORA");
console.log(u.key); //this line is problematic
```

How can i inform typescript about existence of `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature does not yet exist in TypeScript. However, there is [an open GitHub feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) that has been around since 2015 which has lots of support, though it seems that the TypeScript team won't implement or consider it until the [JS decorator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) is finished and supported by browsers.

Comment: If you find an answer useful, you can mark it as accepted 15 minutes after the question is posted.

Comment: thanks, but do you have any work around for this at the moment

Comment: Unfortunately, not really, but you could use something like `@KeyAdder class User implements KeyAdderInterface {}` with `interface KeyAdderInterface { key: "value" }`